# How to specify multiple languages in the GSA feed

Tags: xml, feed, google-search-appliance

We generate GSA feed XMLs from our application. This XML is used by GSA to crawl through the available pages.

Problem:

We have pages for **English**:

http://oursite.com/en/web/design/startpage

And **Deutsch**:

http://oursite.com/de/web/design/startpage

Is it possible to specify :
http://oursite.com/web/design/startpage

and specify the available *languages* as an attribute?

Comment: Anybody have any idea ? :(

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

The GSA needs specific URL's for indexing. This feature would be nice in your case, but imagine you have to add some Metatags per URL in the feed. Every language has likely own values for them.

What is the exact problem with providing specific url's? You can generate a feed per website language and push them separately per language. That way you can use the same feed with different language parameter per language. That way you can add new languages without any further coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pascal...We had implemented it with the specific language.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution ;) I saw the post date too late ^^ It was on the top 10 of the newest posts :P